# Requiring a txt file in react component breaks jest snapshot

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Inside my react component I import react and then I require a data file.

```
const data = require(data.txt);
```

The txt file holds xml data which I am just requiring. The xml holds data that I use to initially render the component with some dummy data. So in my spec file I want to perform a snapshot.

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import MyComponent from '../';

test('renders a component', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow((
    <MyComponent />
  ));

  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

After I run the test I am getting an error:

```
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

That is where the xml is exactly starting. Is this something to do with the transformer? How can this issue be tackled?

Comment: im guessing you need a file loader for that

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier the loader is used to be able to require txt. So I am using this and the component works in the frontend. Its just the test that is failing. I can bypass it by using moduleNameMapper and set it to Empty but its not ideal.